# Deploying a Java EE application to Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to deploy a Java project on my Tomcat8 server running on Ubuntu machine.

I downloaded the Business suite Zip file from [here](http://www.axelor.com/community/downloads/) then I copied the folder to /tomcat/webapps. When I start tomcat server everything seems fine but I'm not able to access localhost:8080 from my browser it keeps loading with no response.

Then I removed the project folder from /tomcat/webapps and restarted the server and everything working normal.
I don't know why localhost:8080 does not respond when I added the project to /webapps even if the server is running.

Please help me if you have any ideas !

NOTE: I tried to upload .war file to APP MANAGER after running jar cvf dirname.war . but I got an error related to max file size upload.

Comment: Please start tomcat by using command line, run a command line at `bin` folder of tomcat, run command: `startup.bat`. It will start tomcat and keep the command line console, after that, let's copy and paste the `.war` file into `webapps` folder. Refresh `webapps` folder, then go to console to see what happen

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't deploy Java Enterprise App to Tomcat8 (Servlet Container). Because JEE apps requires Enterprise Container like JBoss, Glasfish, Weblogic Server, TomEE.

If you mean deploy Dynamic Web Application (composed like war) generated any Java Supported IDE to Tomcat8 -> You can simple copy it to /tomcat/webapps/ folder and access from browser

http://localhost:port/app_name

or you can config root context on /tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Host>
<!-- Other code stuff -->
<Context path="" docBase="app_name" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
</Host>
```

after this you can access by typing on browser

http://localhost:port    (default port 8080)